# TabWidget - How to set position of indicator text?

Tags: android, tabwidget

i'm trying to use TabHost and TabWidget in my Android application. This is my layout main.xml:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/mainTabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="65px"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentTags"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentPreferences"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And my code:

```
final TabHost mainTabHost = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.mainTabHost);
mainTabHost.setup();
final TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecTags = mainTabHost.newTabSpec("tabTags");
tabSpecTags.setIndicator(this.getString(R.string.tab_name_tags));
tabSpecTags.setContent(R.id.contentTags);
mainTabHost.addTab(tabSpecTags);
final TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecPreferences = mainTabHost.newTabSpec("tabPreferences");
tabSpecPreferences.setIndicator(this.getString(R.string.tab_name_preferences));
tabSpecPreferences.setContent(R.id.contentPreferences);
mainTabHost.addTab(tabSpecPreferences);
```

The problem is that i do not want my tabs to be so tall (65px). However, if i set the layout_height of the TabWidget to e.g. 30px, i can't see the tab labels (indicator) on the tabs at all.

Seems like there is a "minimum required" height for the TabWidget (65px?) and the indicator is positioned at the bottom of this 65px?

Is there a way to adjust the positioning of the indicator?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Edwin,

can you please share your code with me on how you got your tabs length small and how you got the text to appear as you want. i am in same problem as when ever I decrease the height of my tabs I am loosing the text display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, if i set the layout_height of
>   the TabWidget to e.g. 30px, i can't
>   see the tab labels (indicator) on the
>   tabs at all.

Note that the techniques for doing this won't necessarily be reliable in future Android releases, if they change up how a `TabHost` is constructed.

> Is there a way to adjust the
>   positioning of the indicator?

Starting with API Level 4 (a.k.a., Android 1.6), `TabHost.TabSpec` accepts a `View` as the indicator via [`setIndicator()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29). I haven't tried it, but it may give you greater control over the layout of an individual tab's indicator.

Comment: Thanks! i tried it out and yes, i can use a TextView with setIndicator. So all that's left is to configure the TextView. The downside is that it's basically starting from scratch (by default just text with no decoration).

Comment: Well, you can always create a layout XML file for your indicator and inflate it, using that for the `setIndicator()` call.

Answer (score 2):

i see...
when u addTab, usually we use setIndicator like this:
QTabHost.addTab(QTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").bla bla....

u can use TextView to replace "TAB 2", became like this:

tview=new TextView(this);
tview.setText("Title here");
QTabHost.addTab(QTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator(tview).bla bla....

all u need is just modify the textview.
Thanks... ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
int iH = getTabWidget().getLayoutParams().height;

for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = iH;
        }
```

Comment: This worked for me quite well.  I use this code in my TabActivity's onCreate() method, and my layout file has:
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_widget_height" />

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 50;
}
```

by using this we can do very easily

Comment: This post does not work. You can not set height of tab by `tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 50`